# How can I create Alert box with a link that is clickable in the alert box or dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I need a alert box or a dialog box where I can click the url link within the box.

```
   var goToSystemForm = confirm('Please complete System Form and get a signature 

    approval before attaching the form. Would you like to be directed there now?');

    if (goToSystemForm){
        window.location.href = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com';
    }
    else{
        //do something else or nothing?
    }
```

Is there another way to create a alert box where I can click with in the dialog box?

Comment: I need a winning lottery ticket. Can we trade?

Comment: You seem to have confused [so] with reading the manual or [Google](https://google.com). Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions related to code you have written. if you are trying to learn more about a topic, use Google or any of the various training sites out there.

Comment: Then, after [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: alert("want to create a link in a alert box");

Comment: var goToSystemForm = confirm('Please complete System Form and get a signature approval before attaching the form. Would you like to be directed there now?');

if (goToSystemForm){
    window.location.href = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com';
}
else{
    //do something else or nothing?
}

Comment: If you want to make your own HTML popup that temporarily disables all controls on the page while it's active, you need a [modal dialog](https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+modal+dialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

http://jquerymodal.com/

Then you can design your own html-popup-window.